# Microsoft Report builder execute query greyed out

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am having the following stored procedure, the procedure is deployed in the same database where the data are stored.

I was trying to use Microsoft Report builder to add this dataset but the option "execute query" is greyed out. No field can be recognized, only with "edit as text" can the stored procedure be executed and return the results.

Can Anybody help me to find out why? I've been getting stuck here for quite a while.

[image]

```
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @time_from  nvarchar(50)    =   '12:00:00'
,       @time_to    nvarchar(50)    =   '24:00:00'

/***************current hour Average***************/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #hour_average
CREATE TABLE #hour_average ( V1a INT,
                             V2a INT,
                             V3a Int)
INSERT INTO #hour_average
select AVG(V1) as V1a
    ,  AVG(V2) as V2a
    ,  AVG(V3) as V3a

FROM [phone].[schema].[vwCall] with (nolock)
where DATEPART(hour,CallDateTime)=DATEPART(hour,getdate())
and CallDate=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
and CallJN=1
AND CallDateTime  BETWEEN @time_from AND @time_to
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour,CallDateTime)
ORDER BY DATEPART(hour,CallDateTime) asc

/************current day Average******************/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #day_average
CREATE TABLE #day_average ( V1_day_a INT,
                            V2_day_a INT,
                            V3_day_a INT )
INSERT INTO #day_average
SELECT AVG(V1) as V1_day_a
    ,  AVG(V2) as V2_day_a
    ,  AVG(V3) as V3_Day_a
FROM [phone].[schema].[vwCall] with (nolock)
where CallDate=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
and CallJN=1
AND CallDateTime  BETWEEN @time_from AND @time_to 

/*********Get the results*********/


SELECT 'Hour' as Timeframe,* 
INTO #results
from #hour_average 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Day' as Timeframe,* 
from #day_average

SELECT ISNULL (Timeframe,0)Timeframe, V1, V2,V3 FROM #results
END
```

Comment: Are you putting the above query in your Query Type  Text selection space? Or is that just part of the SP? You should be able to use Stored Procedure and use that as your dataset. Simply select Stored Procedure and select the name of the procedure. share screedshots perhaps?

Comment: @Harry This is already the SP, I chose it from the database and wanted to save it as a new dataset, but I could not save it because the error says: there is no field and can not be saved

Answer (score 0):

I have searched online and found out the problem was caused by temporary table and meta data. Add @FMTONLY has solved the problem.
Here is the original article about it with code in it:https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1009971/Stored-Procedure-Returns-No-Fields-Even-After-Refr